# Increment by one value is not work while using large length of digit?

Tags: php, if-statement

Currently i am tried to increment value by one but is not working while taking large length of digit.

For example..

Right now `st_id` is store in database like `G4KZ00000001` now what i want when it's called second time then value will be increment by 1 so it would be then `G4KZ00000002, G4KZ00000003` etc..

Following is my code..

Value get from DB..

```
$lastStconId =$last_api_record['st_consignment_id'];
```

Then Use following condition

```
if(empty($lastStconId)) {

$consignment_no = 'G4KZ00000001';

}else
{

$dataid = $last_api_record['st_consignment_id'];
$con =    str_replace("G4KZ", "", $dataid);


echo $consignment_no = $con+1; // dynamic
echo $consignment_no = 'G4KZ'.$consignment_no;
}
```

When i print `$consignment_no`  it's always return increment  value but i want it with full string `G4KZ00000002`.

Comment: It looks like your `$con` is a string like `'00000001'`. I'm not sure it's incrementing correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you increment `$consignment_no` with `'00000001'` you are getting `2` as this is a numeric value.  To make it back to the full length you need to pad it out with zeros to the length of the original number.  I use `str_pad()` with left padding with `0`...

```
$consignment_no = 'G4KZ'.str_pad($consignment_no, strlen($con), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to remove and re-add the `G4KZ` prefix at all - you can increment strings just fine in PHP. This also avoids the issue you're having with the padding being removed, since it treats the entire string as the operand.

```
$str = 'G4KZ00000001';

echo ++$str;
```

> G4KZ00000002

See https://3v4l.org/nE8X9 for a demo with a few more iterations.

Comment: Not work still given increment value not full string,